# I want to set flair to my reddit post using PRAW, can someone suggest solution to it?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm learning PRAW API to create bot to autopost things on my subreddit and script it working fine except flair setting. I tried to use this line to set flair:

```
reddit.subreddit(sub_reddit).flair.set('bboe', 'bahissiteleri flair')
```

**[from praw API documentation](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/subredditflair.html)**

can someone suggest me a solution?

```
import praw
sub_reddit = 'bahissiteleri' #this is the subreddit you are posting to.

post_title = 'Check' # this is the post title
post_body = "check" # this is the post text/body


reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id='id',
    client_secret='secret',
    username='username',
    password='password',
    user_agent="Agent to post")

def authenticate(reddit):
    print(reddit.user.me())

def self_post():
    # try:
    # post = reddit.subreddit(sub_reddit).submit(title=post_title, selftext=post_body)
    # reddit.subreddit(sub_reddit).flair.set('bboe', '')
    sub=reddit.subreddit(sub_reddit)
    post = sub.submit(title=post_title, selftext=post_body)

    reddit.subreddit(sub_reddit).flair.set('bboe', 'bahissiteleri flair')
    print("DONE")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    authenticate(reddit)
    self_post()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flair.set` isn't going to change anything in your `post` variable. I think this is what you were going for:

```
def self_post():
    # try:
    # post = reddit.subreddit(sub_reddit).submit(title=post_title, selftext=post_body)
    # reddit.subreddit(sub_reddit).flair.set('bboe', '')
    sub=reddit.subreddit(sub_reddit)
    post = sub.submit(title=post_title, selftext=post_body, flair_id='bboe', flair_text='bahissiteleri flair')
```